# Dependency Injection doesn't know about type that I want to inject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, havebox

I want to use [HaveBox](https://bitbucket.org/Have/havebox/wiki/Home) for Dependency Injection. But it isn't question about [HaveBox](https://bitbucket.org/Have/havebox/wiki/Home). So I created base controller:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected  readonly IRepository m_Repository;

        protected BaseController(IRepository repository)
        {
            m_Repository = repository;
        }
    }
```

And my HomeController was inherited from `BaseController`. Add `HaveBoxConfig.RegisterTypes();` to `Application_Start` method and implementation of `HaveBoxConfig` is:

```
 public class HaveBoxConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterTypes()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Configure(config => config.For<IService>().Use<Service>());
            container.Configure(config => config.For<IRepository>().Use<Repository>());
            IDependencyResolver resolver = DependencyResolver.Current;
            var newResolver = new MyResolver(container, resolver);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(newResolver);
        }
    }
```

And my resolver:

```
public class MyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IContainer m_container;
        private readonly IDependencyResolver m_resolver;
        public MyResolver(IContainer container, IDependencyResolver resolver)
        {
            m_container = container;
            m_resolver = resolver;
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return m_container.GetInstance(serviceType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return m_resolver.GetService(serviceType);
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return m_resolver.GetServices(serviceType);
        }
    }
```

Method `GetService` called for next types: `IControllerFactory`, `IControllerActivator`, `HomeController` but not for my `IRepository`.

What am I doing wrong? Why DI isn't executed for `IRepository`?

Comment: MVC will never request the `IRepository`. It will request the `HomeController`. It's the job of HaveBox to build this `HomeController` with all its dependencies. I'm not familiar with HaveBox, but perhaps the `HomeController` must be registered explicitly. And even if HaveBox allows resolving unregistered concrete types, its best practice to register all root types explicitly in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked different ways to solve it. Most simple is just add my controllers to container. For example:

```
container.Configure(config => config.For<HomeController>().Use<HomeController>());
```

It is simple and clear. If you have complex project and for more graceful solution you can do it via reflection for all classes that implemented `IController` interface.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to implement a controller factory. Easiest way is to subclass [DefaultControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You can check how they do it with [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Windsor-tutorial-part-two-plugging-Windsor-in&NS=Windsor). Then you tell ASP.NET MVC to use your implementation.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(newResolver);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```